# Use sapply/lapply or foreach to access data attributes R

Tags: r, nlp, sapply, parallel.foreach, lemmatization

this could be a very basic question but honestly, I tried a few solutions on those similar questions but was unable to drive success on my data. It could be because of my data or I am having a hard day and couldn't figure out anything. :(

I have a vector of sentences

```
vec = c("having many items", "have an apple", "item")
```

Also, I have a data frame to lemmatize the data

```
lem = data.frame(pattern = c("(items)|(item)", "(has)|(have)|(having)|(had)"), replacement = c("item", "have"))
lem$pattern = as.character(lem$pattern)
lem$replacement = as.character(lem$replacement)
```

I want to go through each row in the `lem` data frame to form a replacement command.

Option 1:

```
library(stringr) #this is said to be quicker than gsub and my data has 3 mil sentences   
vec <- sapply(lem, function(x) str_replace_all(vec, pattern=x$pattern, replacement = x$replacement))

Error in x$pattern : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Option 2:

```
library(doPar)
vec <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(lem)) %dopar% {
str_replace_all(vec, pattern = lem[i, "pattern"], replacement = lem[i, "replacement"])
}
```

Option 2 returns a list of 2 vectors: the first one is what I want, the second one is the original, which I don't know why. Also, I tested on my machine, `doPar` (though using parallel programming) is not as fast as `sapply`.

Since my data is quite big (**3 mil sentences**), could somebody recommend an effective method to lemmatize the text data?

Comment: If you go through `lem` and replace each element of `vec` that is in `lem$pattern` with its replacement, you end up with as many results as there are rows in `lem`, each one corresponding to one replacement, which is what you observe in your Option2.

Comment: Understood! What can I do to avoid that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `doPar`, but you can simply rewrite your vec as in: `for(i in 1:nrow(lem)){vec = str_replace_all(vec,lem$pattern[i],lem$replacement[i])} `

Comment: I can't use a sequential loop, Lamia. My data is too big for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to create a named vector from your pattern and replacement vectors instead of a data frame, and then use `str_replace_all` directly, like this:

```
library(stringr)

vec <- c("having many items", "has an apple", "items")

lem <- c("item", "have")
names(lem) <- c("(items)|(item)", "(has)|(have)|(having)|(had)")

str_replace_all(vec, lem)

## "have many item" "have an apple"  "item"
```

Comment: Cool! I hadn't never seen this option of str_replace_all.

Comment: `lem` is actually a *.csv file having two columns. By using this technique, I suppose I need to transpose the data frame and use the `pattern` column as the name

Comment: Not really. From the data frame, you just do this: `lems <- lem$replacement` and `names(lems) <- lem$pattern`, and then do `str_replace_all` with `lems` instead of `lem`

Comment: This isn't necessarily the solution which I was looking for since I was keen on finding a way to use `sapply` (`foreach`) but it solves my problem. It runs very quickly on a 3 mil data points. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `stri_replace_all_regex` from the `stringi` library, which will perform your replacements sequentially:

```
library(stringi)
stri_replace_all_regex(vec,lem$pattern,lem$replacement,vectorize_all=F)
[1] "have many item" "have an apple"  "item"
```

Comment: Let me try your solution on my dataset to see how it goes performance-wise. I am more keen to have a parallel programming solution though.